# Unable to execute FSCommand:flashstudio in Flash

Tags: flash, flashdevelop

I'm looking for a program called Multidmedia Flash Player PRO SWF2EXE. The program has been discontinued for a long time, and I couldn't find any information about it. When searching for FSCommand:flashstudio, I only come across screenshots of the program, but no download links. The program used to be a paid software, but it later transitioned to Zinc 4.0. The reason I'm specifically searching for the program Flash Player PRO SWF2EXE is because it can execute the FSCommand:flashstudio command, which Zinc cannot do. Does anyone have any suggestions?

I tried doing it with the Macromedia program, and it didn't work. I tried with Flash Build, and it didn't work either. I also tried with Zinc 4.0, but it didn't work